# Security Concerns with NetLogo

Tags: java, security, netlogo

I'm quite new to NetLogo, but I'm very interested in learning more about it.  Currently I'm trying to get my company to allow it to be installed on our corporate network, however I'm being denied by IT security because "The product is capable of producing stand-alone executables."

So my questions to you guys are:

Is NetLogo capable of compiling java code, or does it merely use externally-created (via another not included program) JAR files as extensions?

Are any of the programs (Netlogo, Netlogo 3D, HubNet, or Behaviorsearch) included with the NetLogo 64 or 32-bit installers capable of creating standalone executables?

Do you know of any way to leverage the Netlogo suite for malicious purposes?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Jeff

Comment: sorry, can't help definitively, but there are NetLogo developers who answer questions regularly here. Previous versions of NetLogo were able to create a jar file that ran the model without having NetLogo on the computer. I believe this has been depreciated, but it might be the source of the concern.

Comment: Good info.  Thank you.  Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

> Previous versions of NetLogo were able to create a jar file that ran the model without having NetLogo on the computer. I believe this has been depreciated, but it might be the source of the concern.

This seems to be in reference to NetLogo applets. It's true that the newest versions of NetLogo don't allow making applets anymore. But even in the older versions that have applets, the `NetLogoLite.jar` file used is precompiled and is always the same, only the `.nlogo` file varies from model to model.

> Is NetLogo capable of compiling java code

no

> or does it merely use externally-created (via another not included program) JAR files as extensions?

yes

> Are any of the programs (Netlogo, Netlogo 3D, HubNet, or Behaviorsearch) included with the NetLogo 64 or 32-bit installers capable of creating standalone executables?

no

> Do you know of any way to leverage the Netlogo suite for malicious purposes?

Yes, you can write an `.nlogo` file that does something malicious when run (run within NetLogo, not standalone), most easily by using the https://github.com/NetLogo/Shell-Extension/ . You could even put the malicious code in the model's `startup` procedure.